# Flow of ipv4 over ipv6 tunnel

Tags: ipv6, ipv4

Re-posting my question from stackoverflow

I am trying to achieve flow of ipv4 packets over ipv6 tunnel between 2 machines. Initially i had the following setup

```
Linux1 eth0                                Linux2 eth0
128.247.19.203                            128.247.19.77
2000::1/64  ---------ipv6 tunnel-----   2000::3/64
```

When i do a ping from Linux 1, i.e ping 128.247.19.77, the ping goes through, but i do not see ESP packets in wireshark. I am thinking these packets do not go through the ipv6 tunnel. I am thinking my setup might be wrong here.

So, i have come up with the following set up

```
Linux1                                         Linux2
eth0.1 -128.247.19.203                         eth0.1 128.247.19.77
eth0 2000::1/64  -----ipv6 tunnel------        eth0 2000::3/64
```

I am thinking if do ping 128.247.19.77 from Linux1, the ipv4 packet goes through the ipv6 tunnel ( i.e starts at eth0.1 , goes through eth0, reaches other end to eth0 on Linnux2 and then eth0.1). Is my understanding right? Also the ping does not work. I have added 128.247.19.77 as default gateway.

Please let me know if my understanding is right and correct me i am wrong.

here is my ipsec.conf file

```
# ipsec.conf - strongSwan IPsec configuration file
config setup
    strictcrlpolicy=no
    charondebug=all

conn %default
    left=128.247.19.77
    leftcert=/home/root/alphaCert.der
    leftid="C=US, O=Test, CN=alpha.test.org"
    right=128.247.19.92
    rightid="C=US, O=Test, CN=beta.test.org"
    keyexchange=ikev2
    ike=aes128-sha1-modp2048!
    type=tunnel
    esp=aes128ctr-sha1-modp2048-noesn!
    lifetime=168h
    ikelifetime=168h 
    reauth=no   
    mobike=no
    mediation=no

conn Alpha-Udp2
    leftprotoport=icmp
    leftsubnet=2000::3/64
    rightprotoport=icmp
    rightsubnet=2000::1/64
    auto=start
```

Comment: Sander Steffan commented that the global IPV6 address i am using might be wrong. More feedback will be much appreciated and helps me in learning. Btw, i have setup the IPSEC tunnel using IKE strongswan.

Comment: Then please show your config. IPv6 and IPSec have nothing to do with each other. Your IPv6 tunnel will be used when you use the IPv6 protocol, not when using IPv4 addresses.

Comment: Thanks for commenting Steffan. What i want to do is send inner ipv4 data over the outer ipv6 tunnel. From the conf file, i believe, i have a ipv6 tunnel between 2000::1/64 and 2000::3/64. The ipsec status confirms this. I also tried ping6. Not sure if i should change the leftprotoport and righprotoport?

Comment: You are tunnelling IPv6 over IPv4